# Remove item from php loop

Tags: php, loops, slice

I have a loop which index files if folder named "data" and show all files as loop. In extra it checks for url string and if there is subfolder (data/folderrandom) described in string "d" (index.php?d=folderrandom) then it shows files of that sub-folder!

I want to slice out two files named "downloadHTML" and "downloadPHP" which are stored in "data" folder from the loop. I would like to slice the item contain above file name! Some part of loop code is as below

```
if(count($files) >= 1){
foreach ($files as $file) { 
    $nb++;
    if (!is_dir($file)) {
?>

    <div class="tab icon">hi
    <?php if($folders){ ?>
        <a href="index.php?p=view&f=<?php echo $nb; ?>&d=<?php echo $folders; ?>">
    <?php }else{ ?>
        <a href="index.php?p=view&f=<?php echo $nb; ?>">
    <?php 
        }
        $info = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", $file);
        echo basename($info);
        $blocks[$nb] = $file; 
        ?>
    </a>
</div>
<?php 
    }else{
    $file_name =  basename($file);  
?>
```

The below php code slice item from left and right what you like. Its very useful, and can help to get answer.

```
<?
function arem($array,$value){
    $holding=array();
    foreach($array as $k => $v){
        if($value!=$v){
            $holding[$k]=$v;
        }
    }    
    return $holding;
}

function akrem($array,$key){
    $holding=array();
    foreach($array as $k => $v){
        if($key!=$k){
            $holding[$k]=$v;
        }
    }    
    return $holding;
}

$lunch = array('sandwich' => 'cheese', 'cookie'=>'oatmeal','drink' => 'tea','fruit' => 'apple');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($lunch);
$lunch=arem($lunch,'apple');
print_r($lunch);
$lunch=akrem($lunch,'sandwich');
print_r($lunch);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Can seek this example from php.net
$array['admin'] = array('blah1', 'blah2');
$array['voice'] = array('blah3', 'blah4');
array_cut('blah4', $array);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `slice` do you mean don't show them in the output? If so, you could throw this into your foreach loop:

```
foreach ($files as $file) { 
    $nb++;
    if(preg_match("/downloadHTML|downloadPHP/i", $file)){
        continue;
    }
    // The rest of the foreach
}
```

Comment: oh man! You made my day! Thank you! +1 your answer!
Also you can see extra code that I added in question, it may help you in future!